# js function does not work when invoked externally

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know this is silly but i think i cant crack it for last couple of hours.
I am writing to understand how this works.
I have a simple js function that i want it to be kept in an external file and it just dont work when invoked from my .php file.

Here is the setup:
I have 4 separate php files like register.php, dashboard.php, header.php, actions.php

I have defined some functions in my script.js like below

```
function fn1(){
alert("fn1");
} 

function fn2(){
alert("fn2");
}

function fn3(){
alert("fn3");
}
```

Now, I have defined in my header.php to include this script file as

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body>
 <script src='/js/script.js'></script>
</body>
...
```

I include this header.php in my other php files like

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<script language="javascript">
fn1();
</script>
```

This does not work. It says ..

SyntaxError: syntax error script.js:1

ReferenceError: fn1 is not defined dashboard.php

Is there something wrong in the way i setup and distribute them into separate files ?

The same function if i locally define in these php files separately, it works fine.
So its a problem only when invoked from an external js script.

Please suggest what am i doing wrong.

I have bunch of functions that i wrote earlier which works fine but i want to understand this first so that i can go on with moving those functions in the same way to keep them global.

**What i want to acheive ?**

I have PHP files based on the view/actions as follows ..

login.php 
   register.php 
   dashboard.php 
   useraction.php 
   header.php

there are several div's like my navbar, footer, sidebar that are common to all these php's;
header.php has all the required js functions to load these div's based on various conditions and events;

My plan is to include header.php in all my php's so that all the functions defined in it are included too in every php file and the common div's are 
loaded by the header.php itself.

Does it make sense ? Is this the right way to achieve this? If not, how do i do, please clarify.

So as per this plan, i attempted making a simple js function that can be kept in an external js to be called from these php which did not work

Comment: Why on Earth does your _header_ file contain the whole `<body>` section? )

Comment: Raina, I just adjusted that in my original code but that did not help addressing the problem i reported. For now, my header.php contains all the js functions defined locally inside the <script> tag and it works fine as it is the main php file that loads many of the div's asynchronously. since i included header.php in my other php, the common div's that show up in all my views are loaded by the header.php itself while the specific views per that php file would be separately loaded. This is my plan and understanding how to template my php code. Is there any better way of doing it ?

Comment: Well, I'd recommend using [output buffering functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) instead for finer control over the layout structure.

Comment: sorry never used that before; just updated my actual plan.pls let me know what u feel;

Comment: Are you sure that's the only thing in your script.js?

Comment: This pointed me to recheck and it was indeed the path was wrong. Since i was trying it for the first time and the error as per the console log was unusually "syntax" specific i got deviated from checking the very basic thing of its path. Thanks Kevin for shooting it right on my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`language` is deprecated. You should just use `<script>` tags.
The problem is with your first line, you should post that, the posted code works fine, I just tested it. It's probably a syntax mistake.
Still, you should consider loading the scripts in a different php file than the one that takes care of setting up the header and the navbar or what have you.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I said *probably a syntax mistake*, when it clearly is just that:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error script.js:1
```

Delete the first line of your 'script.js' and it should work.

This got it working for me:

header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src='script.js'></script>
```

main.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<script>
fn1();
</script>
```

script.js

```
function fn1(){
    alert("fn1");
} 
function fn2(){
    alert("fn2");
}
function fn3(){
    alert("fn3");
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Suddenly, this seems more a php question.
Your scripts should probably be loaded in a separate php file, scripts.php, that you include in the bottom of a specific php page, but just before opening the `<script>` tags, if there is need for particular js on that page.
This makes for a faster page loading. You could, though, include specific scripts in the header part, even in the document's `<head>`, but you should try to keep those scripts lightweight, so they don't heavily delay the user.
You can include php's anywhere. For example, this could be dashboard.php:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<div id="ImOnlyOnThisParticularPage"></div>

<!-- Footer loads scripts after the <footer> or divs that it contains -->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>

<script>
var iOnlyDoSomethingInThisPage = function()
{
   console.log("debug");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will keep it in mind while i work on splitting the stuff in the next few days. I will come back here to share my comment if i get stuck again in this related.

Answer (score 0):

@param LoL i replicated your code and kept it in separate files and i am getting the alert as expected .In case you have issues open your console panel and try debugging.Press F12 and check for console related errors mostly u don't have your files are correct path